# Change the scheduler from TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() for unit tests

Tags: winforms, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, moq

I'm running a Windows Forms application that need to update the GUI, and therefore *have* to use the scheduler that come from the current synchronization context. Code: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

When writing unit tests - this scheduler need to be switched because we want to use our own scheduler that run stuff concurrently and synchronously in a test. There are alternatives (injection, ManualResetEvent) but that's ugly and we don't want it.

It is possible to modify TaskScheduler.Default by using reflection to overwrite a private variable and that's great, but there is no obvious way of doing the same with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().

So, how do you do this?

Comment: How dependency injection is ugly? That sounds ridiculous for me at least. For me it sounds what you're trying to achieve(reflection to overwrite a private variable) is what ugly. Better approach is to inject a factory which returns your scheduler or inject the scheduler  itself.

Comment: You call DI weird, but you rather use reflection to extract a private variable inside a class? I think you have it mixed :)

Comment: Yeah ok, the ugly thing I referred to was the ManualResetEvent. Injection surely looks niceer, but the actual question remains: how do you change the Scheduler in the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()?

Comment: Post some code to show how you use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` so that it will be easy for us to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing which might work when in a unit testing scenario, is to create a `TestSynchronizationContext` that inherits from `SynchronizationContext`, and assign it with `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext()`. Your `TestSynchronizationContext` class would override `Post` method to instead redirect to the `Send` method, causing it to run synchronously.

You can find the sources [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,f3fef324390199c1) for reference.

Comment: Omg. I'm not able to format my reply here, but here's code for a SyncContext NOT using the Threadpool for work:

`public class InvokeNowSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext{

        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
            d.Invoke(state);
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
            d.Invoke(state);
        }
    }`